Set the date back by 2882 days in command line / bat file
Task: set the clock back 2882 days in a .bat file.   This is a requirement because a batch file calls a sequence of simulations and the task must be performed before executing the sequence.
Apparently this can be done in via powershell, however, I need to summon said task in a .bat file. Bonus points if it does not require administrative privilege
Any actionable feedback to improve this question is appreciated.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-date?view=powershell-7.4&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7.3

This cannot be done with a batch file. Run the PowerShell script within the batch script is the best you can do. Absolutely no reason not to use PowerShell in 2024. If you write the PowerShell script I can explain how to run the .ps1 file from a batch script

Also, totally impossible to change the date without admin privileges. Not from Control Panel, not from command prompt, and not from PowerShell. Only way to do it without is very hacky. You would need to setup an NTP server, configure windows to use said NTP server (requires admin to setup) and then control the date and time through the NTP server, so your script lives on that NTP server instead.

@LPChip, not sure about Windows but other OS will not "jump" to new time if the difference is more than 5 minutes.

@RomeoNinov good point. Of cource, you can force the refresh to the NTP server, and then it will change the date, but it will probably not do it automatically without either restarting the NTP service or a reboot. I do know that windows will update the date and time if the NTP answer is valid and recent.

Why are we talking about any operating system other than Windows? That command would not change the date of a file on anything other than Windows.

Not extensively tested but check if this script helps or gives you some pointers. https://gist.github.com/santa4nt/660631  The script does not actually change the date but does the calculations. This if  works the variable can be passed to DATE command. Just preliminary thoughts. Also not too sure if regional settings will affect the formats.

Use the DATE command. start from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264987/how-to-set-date-to-current-date-using-dos-batch-file-command But you'll have to write the script yourself.

if you can change date/time without admin rights then a normal user can mess up the time for all other users. On Linux you still need the right permission to do that. That said, you can still fake the time for a single process

This script basically checks all valid dates by using the xcopy command which gives an error if you input an invalid date. You need to run it as administrator didn't find a way to run without it or you have to assign the change time\date privilege to the user that runs it.
@echo off

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "skip=1 tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\International" -v "sShortDate"') do set FormatoData=%%a

FOR /L %%a in (0,1,6) do (
                          IF /I "!FormatoData:~%%a,2!"=="dd" (set "PDias=%%a,2")
                          IF /I "!FormatoData:~%%a,2!"=="mm" (set "PMeses=%%a,2")
                          IF /I "!FormatoData:~%%a,4!"=="yyyy" (set "PAno=%%a,4")
                         )

set DataAtual=!Date:~%PAno%!!Date:~%PMeses%!!Date:~%PDias%!
set Ano=!Date:~%PAno%!
set Mes=!Date:~%PMeses%!
set Dia=!Date:~%PDias%!

:: MesNu e DiaNu are the numbers of month and day without zero in the front

set /a MesNu=10000%Mes% %% 10000
set /a DiaNu=10000%Dia% %% 10000
set /a AnoNu=%Ano%

:: DiaAn is equal to previous day

for /L %%a in (1,1,2882) do (
                           IF !DiaNu! GTR 1 (
                                            set /a DiaNu=!DiaNu! - 1
                                            set DiaAn=0!DiaNu!
                                            set DiaAn=!DiaAn:~-2!
                                            set MesAn=0!MesNu!
                                            set MesAn=!MesAn:~-2!
                                            echo !DiaAn!/!MesAn!/!AnoNu!
                                           ) else (
                                                   set Contador=31
                                                   call :MesAnterior
                                                   set DiaAn=0!DiaNu!
                                                   set DiaAn=!DiaAn:~-2!
                                                   set MesAn=0!MesNu!
                                                   set MesAn=!MesAn:~-2!
                                                   echo !DiaAn!/!MesAn!/!AnoNu!
                                                  )
                          )
Date !DiaAn!/!MesAn!/!AnoNu!
pause
Exit

:MesAnterior

IF !MesNu! EQU 1 (set MesNu=12& set /a AnoNu=!AnoNu! - 1) else (set /a MesNu-=1)

xcopy . temp /l /i /d:!MesNu!-!Contador!-!AnoNu! > nul 2>&1
IF /i !Errorlevel! EQU 0 (set DiaNu=!Contador!) else (Set /a Contador=!Contador!-1 & goto :MesAnterior)
goto :EOF

